# custom edit unlike the built-in edit form will not show newly created fields

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, html, design, edit-form

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection. now if i am using the built-in Edit form it will automatically show any new field added to the Enterprise-wiki content type.

But now i wanted to hide specific fields only from the edit form and keep them inside the create & view forms. To be able to do so, i created a custom edit form and i added `Display:none` for all the fields i want to hide. This worked well ,, but now if i added a new field to the enterprisewiki content type it will not be shown automatically inside the custom edit form,, while if i am using the built-in edit form the field will be shown.

now i created a custom edit form , because inside the built-in edit form i can not see the markup for the fields to add `Display:none` , while in the custom edit form i can see the markup and add any custom HTML to it.

so can anyone adivce on this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected when you create a custom editform, and changes to the underlying list structure like fields being created manually or via a content type do not show up. They must be added manually in the custom form.

Sharepoint has behaved this way since 2007 that I know of, and presumably in 2003 and 2001. You are essentially breaking the dynamic association by inserting a custom EditForm. It pulls down the information at that time and then becomes static.

Comment: so what is the idea behind this ? also inside the built-in edit form the only way to hide fields is to use javascript, and i do not want users with java script disabled to be able to access these fields ....

Comment: The default editform will respect the form field settings, if you have a field set to hidden, it will hide it, this again has been unchanged since 2007 that I know of.

Comment: so using a custom edit form will break many SharePoint features...

Comment: Anything custom has the potential to break or impact functionality. This is why they are pushing for people to not do custom master pages and use things like JSLink and CSR to handle the customizations.

Comment: but on many documentations they mentioned that SharePoint support using custom master pages, or using custom edit forms ,, so in my case when i use custom edit form could it break any functionalities?

Comment: You can and it is supported, but you need to know the risks and potential pitfalls. This is a risk by rolling your own edit form, and changes to the list schema are not reflected in your custom page until you add them in yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so now as i mentioned before i want to hide columns from the edit form and keep them inside the create & view forms.. so i did not find any approach to do so except having a custom edit form. because of i hide them from the CT this will affect the view & create forms,, also inside the built-in edit form i can not view and access the related markup to hide the related html,, so if i want to hide them inside the buil-in edit form  i need to use javascript ,, and if user disable javascript , they can view the hidden fields !!!so that do u think ?

Comment: Use CSS instead to hide the fields on the edit form?